# How can I send emails in airflow based on if-else conditions in our python script?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a python script like this:

```
#example.py
def a():
   records=[]
   if len(records)==0:
      #do something
   else:
      #do something
```

I am going to call the function "a" in my airflow script using python operator, now I have to send an email notification with some content if the "if statement" in the function becomes true, if the else statement is executed we shouldn't get any email notification.
How can we achieve this?

Comment: Put code which send email notification after `if` statement and delete `else`.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass context in your function, it can be done by setting provide_context = True in PythonOperator which calls a().

**code (untested)**

```
def a(context):
   records=[]
   if len(records)==0:
      #do something
      email = EmailOperator(task_id="email_task",
                            to ="put reciever email id here",
                            subject="sample_subject",
                            html_content="email content can be html",
                            dag = context.get("dag") )
      email.execute(context=context)


   else:
      #do something
      #your logic


with DAG(dag_id='sample_dag', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args):

    sample_task = PythonOperator(task_id="some_task_id",
                                 python_callable=a,
                                provide_context = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def a(**kwargs):
    records=[]
    if len(records)==0:
        #do something
        email = EmailOperator(
        task_id='send_email',
        to='email@email.com',
        subject='subject',
        html_content='content',
        dag=dag
        )
        email.execute(context=kwargs)
else:
    pass

sample_task = PythonOperator(task_id='some_task_id', python_callable=a, 
provide_context=True, dag=dag)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer